# What is the cost of updating multiple fields in a single call?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From Android example in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), it is clear that we can update multiple fields in a single `update()` call. I was wondering, does this call cost one write or n writes (n = the number of fields updated)?

```
// Assume the document contains:
// {
//   name: "Frank",
//   favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" }
//   age: 12
// }
//
// To update age and favorite color:
db.collection("users").document("frank")
        .update(
                "age", 13,
                "favorites.color", "Red"
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the cost of updating multiple fields in a single call?

It will always cost a single write, no matter how many fields you update in a single `update()` call.

Comment: How about deleting a field? `docRef.update("age", FieldValue.delete(),"favorites.color", "Red")`

Comment: It's the **exact** same thing, still a single write operation.

Comment: I really appreciate your instant answers and replies Alex. BIG thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update should be counted in `writes`, ofcourse. 
I had started using Firestore again for my new project yesterday and did 2 write operations.
I created 2 new documents with multiple fields and it costed me 2 writes.
Then I updated 2 fields in a single document it costed me only 1.

So the answer is, it should cost you only 1 write.

The write count remains 1 irrespective of number of fields in a single document `update()` or `write()`.